# Why is my amount array not returning anything?

Tags: ios, json, swift, for-loop, dispatch

I cant work out why my arrays (amountArray, interestArray and riskbandArray) return the full set of information if I print them just after the forloop, whereas if I print them right at the end of the viewDidload method it returns nothing. I understand that its probably occurring because the network request is being executed in the background so when I ask to print my arrays, nothing is returned because it is being called in the main thread. I have tried to counteract this by bringing in Grand Central Dispatch but my arrays are still empty. SO SO frustrating.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var amountArray = [Int]()
var interestArray = [Double]()
var riskbandArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let Url = NSURL(string: "http://fc-ios-test.herokuapp.com/auctions")
    let task: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(Url!) { (url, response, error) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

            if let array = jsonData["items"] as? [[NSObject:AnyObject]] {

                for item in array {
                    self.amountArray.append(item["amount_cents"] as! Int)
                    self.interestArray.append(item["rate"] as! Double * 100)
                    self.riskbandArray.append(item["risk_band"] as! String)

                }

            }
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        })

    }
    task.resume()


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    print(self.amountArray)
}
```

Comment: like your previous question: your task is asynchonous, therefore is not completed when you print the array.

Comment: is there no way to change that?

Comment: I do not know for sure wether or not that would be possible bu it would surely be a bad idea. Instead move the logic depending on the array into the completion block of the task. If you print the array there you will see that it all works perfectly.

Comment: just put `print(self.amountArray)` right before `self.collectionView?.reloadData()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cut-down version showing the relevant parts of your code:

```
let task: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(Url!) {...}
task.resume()
print(self.amountArray)
```

So you're creating a task and starting it, and then immediately printing `amountArray`. It's important to know that the task will run asynchronously, i.e. it will get processing time periodically until it completes, but execution of your code will continue from the `task.resume()` before the task even really gets going. So your `print()` executes long before the code that would add data to `amountArray` ever happens.

If you want to see what's in `self.amountArray`, move the `print()` statement so that it's the last thing that happens in the task's completion block. It will then happen *after* the array is changed.